# NuGet push to TFS Feed publishes nuget as V2 but TFS Build expect to restore V3

Tags: tfs, nuget

I have setup a NuGet Package feed in TFS 2017 Update 1.
The NuGet Source is as following

> http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/_packaging/NuGet-Feed/nuget/v3/index.json

Following the instructions stated when connecting to TFS Package Feed, I added NuGet source locally and also try to publish package(s) to the NuGet Feed with following format as an example:

```
nuget.exe  push -Source "NuGet-Feed" -ApiKey INCTX Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.1.1.2.nupkg
```

The result of executing above command is as following:

```
Pushing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.1.1.2.nupkg to 'http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/23093bd8-41aa-403d-9d3f-5c713b14ce32/nug
et/v2/'...
  PUT http://mtrlpqdc2av-053:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/23093bd8-41aa-403d-9d3f-5c713b14ce32/nuget/v2/
  Accepted http://mtrlpqdc2av-053:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/23093bd8-41aa-403d-9d3f-5c713b14ce32/nuget/v2/ 1702ms
Your package was pushed.
```

As it shows, the package is published to '***nuget/v2***' endpoint.

Running TFS Build with NuGet Restore task: the following command expects 
 ***nuget/V3/*** endpoint from the TFS Feed which does not exists.
Note: NuGet restore task in TFS build is customized to use NuGet 4.*.* version.

GET http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/23093bd8-41aa-403d-9d3f-5c713b14ce32/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.abstractions/1.1.2/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.abstractions.1.1.2.nupkg

The question I guess is why NuGet Push will publish to 'nuget/v2/' endpoint.

TFS Build NuGet Restore Task output:

```
2017-07-06T15:58:13.0657118Z CredentialProvider.TeamBuild: URI: http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/_packaging/INCTX-NuGet-Feed/nuget/v3/index.json
```

2017-07-06T15:58:13.0657118Z CredentialProvider.TeamBuild: Is retry: False

2017-07-06T15:58:13.0657118Z CredentialProvider.TeamBuild: Matched prefix:

2017-07-06T15:58:13.2688422Z CredentialProvider.TeamBuild: This provider only 
handles URIs from the build's Team Project Collection

2017-07-06T15:58:13.6125991Z   GET tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/23093bd8-41aa-403d-9d3f-5c713b14ce32/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.netcore.app/index.json

2017-07-06T15:58:13.6125991Z   GET tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/23093bd8-41aa-403d-9d3f-5c713b14ce32/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.netcore.app/index.json

2017-07-06T15:58:13.7219799Z   NotFound

Thanks,

Mamrez

Comment: What's the detail error message? The address is correct, you can go to your feed page, then select that package and check the details of Install [package] section.

Comment: I event used NuGet 4.* version. The package push, publishes to **nuget/v2** endpoint, I don't know why?. TFS Build NuGet Restore task, is running the 'GET' command as I stated and is looking for **nuget/v3**. In the feed page, selecting the package also refers to nuget/v3 endpoints. The push does a PUT to nuget/v2 as I mentioned and I don't know why I does that. Updated the question with more results from TFS build task.

Comment: I used NuGet 4.0 and the push endpoint is nugget/v2, the restore endpoint is nugget/v3, but it works fine for me. Could you install package through Nuget.exe? What's the source URL? Try to create a new package and push to feed, then try it with this package.

Comment: You can share a package on the OneDrive.

Comment: I can install the package through with NuGet 4.0 on my laptop with the nuget/v3 restore endpoint. but the TFS NuGet Restore task goes Not Found with nuget/v3 endpoint, that's odd. I use NuGet 4.0 in the NuGet Build restore task, which I put the NuGet 4.0 on the build controller.

Comment: Do you use XAML build or Vnext build? Try to check the [permission of feed](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/feeds/common-identities). You can try to change build service account and try again.

Comment: Running on the TFS App-Tier through command line also issued an error which stated the NuGet source couldn't be reached. Finally figured that which NuGet.config file was being used and as the result, the NuGet publish from TFS start working both on App Tier and in the TFS build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running on the TFS App-Tier through command line also issued an error which stated the NuGet source couldn't be reached.

Finally figured out that which NuGet.config file was being used and as the result, the NuGet publish from TFS start working both on App Tier and in the TFS build.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your nuget.config and reference the following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#push

it says you can either specify it on push or define DefaultPushSource in the config. I might suspect your v2 source is defined as DefaultPushSource in the config.

try: `nuget.exe config DefaultPushSource` to see what it is set to.